# Как обновить QLabel без объекта класса?

Tags: python, qlayout, qlabel, qtimer, pyqt6

Я пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы текст обновлялся каждую секунду, но проблема в том, что я не знаю, как очистить предыдущий текст или обновить существующий.

Создавать объекты класса `QLabel` не вариант, т. к. неизвестно количество строк.

Код:

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QApplication

pl = 0


class Updater(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.upd()

    def upd(self):
        global pl
        for i in range(3):
            self.layout.addWidget(QLabel(f'Текст {i+pl}'))
        pl += 1

        QTimer.singleShot(1000, self.upd)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Updater()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
import random
'''
from PyQt6.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QApplication
'''

from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QApplication


# ??? pl = 0

class Updater(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.upd)
        self.timer.start(1000)
        
#        self.upd()

    def upd(self):
# ???        global pl
      
        while self.layout.count() > 0:
            widget = self.layout.takeAt(0).widget()
            widget.hide()
            widget.deleteLater()
        
#        _range = random.randint(3, 10)
        for i in range(random.randint(3, 10)):
            label = QLabel(f'Текст {i}')                   # ??? +self.pl
            self.layout.addWidget(label)
# ???        self.pl += 1
# ???        QTimer.singleShot(1000, self.upd)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Updater()
    window.resize(200, 300)
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нужно чтобы этот текст впоследствии можно было изменить

Comment: @Sonter ну так и меняйте. Я показал вам как очистить предыдущий текст. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour